# Breaking up R1C1 formula in vba

Tags: vba

I am working on an R1C1 formula that needs multiple "if" conditions.  In order to make it easy to read and debug, I want to break it up into different lines.  I am using " & _ in first line and then start the next line with ".  However, I think I am missing something because I get compile error saying Expected: List separator or ).  Below is the code I am working on.  Any help with this would be much appreciated.

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = IFERROR(" & _
"IF(RC5>=0.75," & _
"IF(AND(RC16=0,RC20=0),""No Action Req: None of the Predictors have an Estimate""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16=0,RC20<>0,RC8>RC9),""Less Similar Comp Retained: Check if P1 is important, no action req. otherwise""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20=0,RC9>RC8),""Less Similar Comp Retained: Check if P2 is important, no action req. otherwise""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16=0,RC20<>0,RC8<RC9),""No Action Req: Model is retaining more similar comp.""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20=0,RC9<RC8),""No Action Req: Model is retaining more similar comp.""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20<>0,RC8>=70%,RC9>=70%),""Keep Both: Both similar comps""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20<>0)," & _
"if(abs(RC8-RC9)<=5," & _
    "if((RC8/RC6)<(RC9/RC7),""Drop P1: P1 wins over P2 wrt score and count"",""Drop P2: P2 wins over P1 wrt score and count"")," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20<>0,RC8<RC9),""Drop P1: P2 is more similar to TGT""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20<>0,RC9<RC8),""Drop P2: P1 is more similar to TGT""," & _
"""""))))))))))),"""")
```

Comment: The string literals aren't escaping the double quotes, e.g. `""No Action Req...""` - but that alone doesn't fix it - to be honest that formula is a maintenance nightmare - seriously consider implementing that logic in actual `If...ElseIf` conditions in actual VBA code instead of coming up with a formula that does it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a double quote here:

> ```
> Selection.FormulaR1C1 = IFERROR(" & _
> ```

Should be (note the opening `=`):

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(" & _
```

And then, every string literal in the formula needs to have its double quotes escaped (i.e. doubled-up).

This code compiles and correctly sets the formula:

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(" & _
"IF(RC5>=0.75," & _
"IF(AND(RC16=0,RC20=0),""No Action Req: None of the Predictors have an Estimate""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16=0,RC20<>0,RC8>RC9),""Less Similar Comp Retained: Check if P1 is important, no action req. otherwise""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20=0,RC9>RC8),""Less Similar Comp Retained: Check if P2 is important, no action req. otherwise""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16=0,RC20<>0,RC8<RC9),""No Action Req: Model is retaining more similar comp.""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20=0,RC9<RC8),""No Action Req: Model is retaining more similar comp.""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20<>0,RC8>=70%,RC9>=70%),""Keep Both: Both similar comps""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20<>0)," & _
"if(abs(RC8-RC9)<=5," & _
    "if((RC8/RC6)<(RC9/RC7),""Drop P1: P1 wins over P2 wrt score and count"",""Drop P2: P2 wins over P1 wrt score and count"")," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20<>0,RC8<RC9),""Drop P1: P2 is more similar to TGT""," & _
"IF(AND(RC16<>0,RC20<>0,RC9<RC8),""Drop P2: P1 is more similar to TGT""," & _
"""""))))))))))),"""")"
```

However I don't have sample data and the formula evaluates to `FALSE` for me, which means something is probably wrong with the nested conditional logic itself - and to be honest I wouldn't want to debug this kind of formula.

Working against `Selection` is dangerous. Seriously consider working against a specific `Range` object, if that's what you mean to be doing - here's a trivial example (which may or may not be what you need):

```
Dim targetCell As Range
Set targetCell = Sheet1.Range("A1")

targetCell.FormulaR1C1 = ...
```

The real solution IMO, would be to drop the idea of evaluating that cell with a formula, and instead implement the conditional logic in actual VBA code. You'll need to `Set` a `Range` object reference representing `RC5`, `RC16`, and every other cell you're using (give them meaningful names). The result might look something like this:

```
Dim result As String
If WhateverRC5is.Value >= 0.75 Then
    If WhateverRC16Is.Value = 0 And WhateverRC20is.Value = 0 Then
        result = "No Action Req: None of the Predictors have an Estimate"
    ElseIf WhateverRC16Is.Value = 0 And WhateverRC20is.Value <> 0 And WhateverRC8is.Value > WhateverRC9is.Value Then
        result = "Less similar comp retained: check if P1 is important.."
    ElseIf ...
    ...
    End If
Else
    '...
End If
targetCell.Value = result
```

Having actual VBA code, with proper indentation and compile-time validation, will be MUCH easier to maintain and debug than whatever layout you can come up with to make that fiendish string digestible.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  This helped a lot.  Also, thank you for suggesting better alternative.  I tried to do this with if - elseif logic in VBA initially but the number of cells I need to evaluate with this logic runs in thousands.  I believe loops might take very long to process this.  I agree, it's a pain to debug this formula but it works faster than the loop. Additionally, I want to evaluate only visible cells with this after applying a few filters and I don't know how to apply a loop that would only evaluate visible cells. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: @Aqua If you were to put the inputs in an array, loop the array and output the results to another array, then post the array into the desired cells it would be faster than the formula and easier to read in vba.

Comment: @Aqua write a function that evaluates what the result should be for one row, parameterize it with a row number, then invoke the function in a loop that iterates all the rows you need to run it for.